# Prints string on console with cout.write() function only after I Quit the application

Tags: c++, console

Inserting an string using cin.getline() and want to print that string on 
console using cout.write().Prints the entered string after I quit the application

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() {
char str[20];
cout<<"Enter a string:";
cin.getline(str,20);
cout<<"Entered string:";
cout.write(str,20);
cout.flush();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put `cout.flush();` after `cout.write(str,20);`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ its working but its also printing '<' after the string. I am using Turbo C++ for practice.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @AyushiSharma I'm explaining the behavior in more depth in the answer I wrote.

Comment: @AyushiSharma BTW `<iostream.h>` and `<conio.h>` aren't standard c++ headers. You're probably using the turbo-c++ compiler that was already deprecate at the end of the last millenium. Consider to use a more modern compiler to learn c++.

Comment: @AyushiSharma don't edit peoples answers into your question, it means that your code now doesn't exhibit the problem stated in your question which is a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

Output to streams is usually *buffered*. Unless the buffer is flushed (which happens when you fill the buffer completely, or explicitly [flush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) it) then the output won't actually be written.

The stream buffer is also flushed when the stream object is closed, which happens when `std::cout` is destructed as part of program termination. That's why you see the output when the program exits.

So the solution is simple: Explicitly flush the buffer (using e.g. `std::cout.flush();`) after each write.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream`implementations like `std::cout` work buffered usually. That means the `std::ostream` implementation collects what's passed with calls to `write()` in a buffer, and only if the buffer is exhausted, the actual contents will be sent to the physical device (a terminal, or a file manifested at the storage).

To trigger the stream writing the buffer contents to the terminal or a file, you explicitely have to call [`std::ostream::flush()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) (note that the `std::endl` I/O manipulator does that implicitely).